Empty message event in SSE using NestJS
I'm trying to do event emitter on SSE in NestJS. Here's my code:
@Sse('sse')
  sse(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(map((_) => ({ data: { hello: 'world' } }) as MessageEvent));
    // return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter, 'new-order').pipe(
    //   map((data) => {
    //     return new MessageEvent('new-order', { data: 'new order' });
    //   }),
    // );
  }

I tried to replicate interval function from docs to check if this will be working.
In both of above return functions events are emitted but on the frontend side only event that is working is onopen.
this.eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/sse');
this.eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
  console.log('Open');
};
this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log('New message: ' + event.data);
};

In Devtools Network interval is registered every second, but Eventstream tab is empty.

EDIT:
With following approach everything works good. But I'm still curious what could be wrong with my previous example.
 @Sse('sse')
  sse(): Observable<any> {
    return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter, 'new-order')
  }

  @Post('sse/emit')
  emit() {
    const message = `Server Time: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`
    return this.eventEmitter.emit('new-order', `data: ${JSON.stringify(message)}\n\n` );
  }

EDIT2:
Looks like I found something that blocks this events. That piece of code to organize my DTOs:
...
app.useGlobalInterceptors(
    new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector), {
      strategy: 'excludeAll',
      excludeExtraneousValues: true,
    }),
  );
...

When I remove it, all works as expected but I don't want to do this. So I created SSEDto(based by MessageEvent object from console) and use it in my SSE endpoint:
export class SSEDto {
    
    @Expose()
    data: string | object;

    @Expose()
    id?: string;

    @Expose()
    type?: string;

    @Expose()
    retry?: number;

    @Expose()
    defaultPrevented: boolean;

    @Expose()
    cancelable: boolean;

    @Expose()
    timeStamp: Timestamp;

}

and in endpoint:
const message = {
      hello: 'world'
    }
return fromEvent(this.eventEmitter, 'new-order')
    .pipe(
      map(data => {       
        const event = new MessageEvent('new-order', {data: message});
        return plainToInstance(SSEDto, event);
      })
    );

Event type etc. is working but this time event.data is empty.
I assume that something is wrong in DTO. Maybe data properties should be exposed too.
